# How do you add results from PayPal IPN to update database

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am looking to be able to take the info from the PayPal IPN post, and use certain items to update my database. This is the current code I have for my ipn.php

```
<?php
// tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

// intantiate the IPN listener
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
$listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {

$errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

// 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
    // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
    exit(0); 
}

// 2. Make sure seller email matches your primary account email.
if ($_POST['receiver_email'] != 'PRIMARY EMAIL ADDRESS') {
    $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
    $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
}

// 3. Make sure the currency code matches
if ($_POST['mc_currency'] != 'USD') {
    $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
    $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
}

// 4. Ensure the transaction is not a duplicate.
mysql_connect('localhost', '[DB_USER]', '[DB_PW') or exit(0);
mysql_select_db('DB_NAME') or exit(0);

$txn_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txn_id']);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'";
$r = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$r) {
    error_log(mysql_error());
    exit(0);
}

$exists = mysql_result($r, 0);
mysql_free_result($r);

if ($exists) {
    $errmsg .= "'txn_id' has already been processed: ".$_POST['txn_id']."\n";
}

if (!empty($errmsg)) {

    // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
    $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
    $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
    mail('NOTIFICATION EMAIL ADDRESS', 'IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

} else {

    <?php 
    $csvData = file_get_contents($_POST['custom']); 
    $csvNumColumns = 3; 
    $csvDelim = ";"; 
    $data = array_chunk(str_getcsv($csvData, $csvDelim), $csvNumColumns); 
    ?>

    // add this order to a table
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
    $credit_amount = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_number']);
    $type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['custom']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES 
         (NULL, '$user_id', '$credit_amount', '$type')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        error_log(mysql_error());
        exit(0);

    }


}

} else {
    // manually investigate the invalid IPN
    mail('NOTIFICATION EMAIL ADDRESS', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}

?>
```

This seemed to work fine when testing it with PayPal Sandbox's IPN testing service and I could enter in the needed values for item_name, item_number, and custom (or when using the below code)

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="SANDBOX EMAIL ADDRESS">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.99">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$this->package['0']['delivered'];?>"
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$_SESSION["user_id"]?>"
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?=$this->package['0']['number'];?>"
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="WEBSITE_URL/success">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="WEBSITE_URL/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
    border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

However I soon realized that it would be much better for the 'item_name' to be something recognizable by the customer, rather than having it be defined as the 'user_id'. Is it possible to have the 'custom' pass through defined as all 3 of the variables that I need, separating them within the PayPal button with semicolons (as seem below)

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$_SESSION["user_id"]?>;<?=$this->package['0']['number'];?>;<?=$this->package['0']['delivered'];?>"
```

then using something like

```
<?php 
    $csvData = file_get_contents($_POST['custom']); 
    $csvNumColumns = 3; 
    $csvDelim = ";"; 
    $data = array_chunk(str_getcsv($csvData, $csvDelim), $csvNumColumns); 
    ?>
```

to give me separate variables that can then be defined as 'user_id', 'credit_amount', and 'type'

once these variables are separated and defined, they are to be posted to the database, however, if there is already a column within the table that has the same 'user_id' as is trying to be posted AS WELL AS the same 'type' that is trying to be posted, then it should only update that row (the row already within the table before the attempted addition) by ADDING the 'credit_amount' to the corresponding 'credit_amount' cell in the old row.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple values, and have them populated into a single variable such as the variable "custom".  There would not be an issue with this.  I have done this myself as well in the past.  When I coded this, I used the | to separate the values, and then had my IPN parse out the values within my IPN script.

Comment: Yes, great, I cannot say I am 100% familiar with PHP, nor have I ever used IPN before (with the exception of a preconfigured listener within a script), and I am unsure of how exactly to have my IPN parse out the values within the script and then define them as separate values, if you could please post the snipit of code that you used for this, I am sure that I would be able to adapt it and use it to solve my problem. Also, would you have any ideas on how to have the row updated instead of a new row being created when the 2 values match? Much appreciated.